# How to make a smarter autocomplete where the . character can match any character in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using this [code](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_autocomplete) I would like to change it a bit so that it is smarter so for example if I search for .an.d I want all the words that have a "a" at the second postion and a "n" at the third potions and again any characther at the fourh postion and a "d" at the fifth postion how can I modify the code to get the desired result thank you very much.

Comment: you could look into [Regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: I have but how do I then pass the list to the autocomplete function? @Ajex

Comment: Here is something to start with `new RegExp("^"+val.toUpperCase()).test(arr[i].toUpperCase())` , it should return true if matches your condition.

Comment: But you probably need some extra logic for the match highlighting in bold.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with regExp, but you might want to do some escaping, otherwise the results might not be what you expect.

eg. searching for `$5` expecting to find something that's got `$5` will not work.

So one solution is first split by `.`, to preserve the `.` for regex, then for each split do the escape using something like -> [Escape string for use in Javascript regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446170/escape-string-for-use-in-javascript-regex) and then finally join back the `.`

eg.

```js
function escapeRegExp(string) {
    return string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&'); // $& means the whole matched string
}

function isMatch(value, search) {
  return new RegExp(
    '^'+search.split('.')
      .map(escapeRegExp)
      .join('.')
  ).test(value);
}

console.log(isMatch('Ban d','.an.d'));
console.log(isMatch('Cost $5', '.....$5'));

console.log(isMatch('xBan d','.an.d'));
```

Comment: You would need to add "^" in front of your regex, otherwise it wouldn't work with absolute position.

Comment: @Ajex that's true, I'll update.